# Custom Middleware not worked on live server python django

Tags: python, django, server, middleware, live

When enable custom middleware in setting.py file in live server then the django application shows an error in browser:

*We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.*

error id: 1312e065.

**N.B in localhost server there was no issue.**

Setting.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [ 
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'userAuth.custom_middleware.RequestLoggerMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'userAuth.middleware.InactivityTimeoutMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',  
]
```

middleware.py:

`class InactivityTimeoutMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            session_key = request.session.session_key
            if session_key:
                session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
                last_activity = session.get_decoded().get('_session_last_activity')

                if last_activity:
                    idle_time = timezone.now() - last_activity
                    if idle_time > timedelta(minutes=5):
                        # User has been inactive for more than 5 minutes, log them out
                        request.session.flush()

        return response`

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 4 conditions that might just silently fail. You should add some kind of debugging output to them.